# Proof that $|\mathbb{R}|=|\mathbb{R}^2|$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Theorem 3 of the chapter "Sets, functions, and the continuum, hypothesis" in the book *"Proofs from the book"*, says that the set $\mathbb{R}^2$ has the same size of the set $\mathbb{R}$ and as a proof a bijection between the sets is described:

For every $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$ write them in their unique non-terminating decimal expansion such that every non-zero number is grouped with all the preceding zeroes (if any), like this:
$$x=0. \quad 003 \quad 4 \quad 09 \quad 0007 \cdots$$
Then, after breaking $x$ and $y$ to such groups we concatenate group 1 of $x$, group 1 of $y$, group 2 of $x$ , group 2 of $y$ and so on.

The entire (short) proof can be shown here:
[image]

I have 3 questions regarding this method:

1. Why the simpler method is not offered, i.e. taking a digit from each number one by one?
2. In the method offered, how we will deal with $x=0.5$ and $y=0.33333\cdots$ i.e.? I don't understand how it can be reversed.
3. Why it says that *"since neither $x$ nor $y$ exhibits only zeros from a certain point on..."*? what about rational numbers as 0.5? 0.25? etc

Comment: I though that $0.5$ had a terminating representation. Surely you mean $0.4\overline 9$.

Comment: Thanks, I've thought that the non-terminating representation of $0.5$ is $0.5 \overline 0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that

> we write $x,y$ in their unique non-terminating decimal expansion[s],

so for $\frac12$ we write $0.4999\ldots$, not $0.5$, and for $\frac14$ we write $0.24999\ldots$, not $0.25$. This takes care of your second and third questions.

The answer to your first question involves the same point. Let $z=0.010101\ldots$. If $f$ worked by simply interleaving the decimal expansions of its arguments, $z$ would have to be $f\left(0,\frac19\right)$, and $0\notin(0,1]$. For that matter, even if you change the first digit of $z$ to $1$, you have a problem, since $z$ is then $f\left(\frac1{10},\frac19\right)$, but you’re using the wrong representation for $\frac1{10}$: you should be using the non-terminating expansion $0.0999\ldots$. The method actually used ensures that $f$ is a bijection, not just an injection.

Comment: Thx a lot! (15 chars)

Comment: @Amihai: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 2):

Taking one digit from each number at a time gets you into the problems with numbers that have two decimal representations -- for example $0.5000\ldots = 0.4999\ldots$. The pair $(\frac12,\frac 12)$ would need to map to all four of
$$ \begin{align} & 0.55000000\ldots \\ & 0.54090909\ldots \\ & 0.45909090\ldots \\ & 0.44999999\ldots \end{align} $$

You'll have to choose one of them (and if you choose $0.44999\ldots=0.45$ you'd better make sure you don't also choose that as the image of $(\frac25,\frac12)$), but then the map is not *surjective* anymore -- there's no other pair than $(\frac12,\frac12)$ that can map to *either* of $0.540909\ldots$ and $0.459090\ldots$ by simple digit-by-digit interlacing, so at least one of those would go unmatched.

It turns out that there are few enough trouble spots that they can be handled by special corrections *after* the simple digit interlacing, but those solutions take a lot of words and care to *explain*. The nice thing about the Book proof is that it sidesteps the need for such corrections completely, with almost *no* extra complexity.